# How to sql join on encoded and decoded url columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, arabic, azure-synapse

I have two tables that I need to join on the URL column in each (A.URL = B.URL).
However the problem is that URLs in Table A are percent encoded (mostly Arabic URLs), whereas the URLs in Table B are not encoded.

For example:

```
A.URL: https://www.aljazeera.net/news/politics/2021/10/20/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-14

B.URL: https://www.aljazeera.net/news/politics/2021/10/20/السودان-14
```

How can I join them in TSQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TSQL - How to URL Encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905193/tsql-how-to-url-encode)

Comment: No it doens't @Charlieface; sys.fn_varbintohexstr doesn't work on Synapse.

Comment: There are other answers there also, perhaps one of them works?

Comment: They don't work for Arabic as far as i can tell, @Charlieface. Some say explicitly that they only work for ASCII, others have the same features in the code.

Comment: this could be done by writing an SQLCLR udf, but there is a bit of a learning curve, and time required to set things up permission wise. And your environment may not allow it to be run.