# Does Pervasive Have a SQL Function for URL Encoding?

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I've written a query that builds some URLs to an intranet site, but some of the URLs don't work because they contain special characters that need to be [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). I'm trying to avoid writing a script (outside of SQL) to do the URL encoding; I'd like the database to do URL-Encoding instead, so that I can just export the data (as is) directly into csv file.

For example, I can encode just one character quite easily. Here, I encode `&` to `%26`:

```
select
     customer_id 
    ,customer_name
    ,'https://intranet.local/customer/?id=' + replace(customer_id,'&','%26') as url
from customer
```

However, this method becomes quite verbose when encoding multiple characters.

Is there a [function in Pervasive 13](https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/#page/sqlref%2Fscalarfunc.htm) that will do URL-encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer give [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853102/724039), you can create a function using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION urlencode(:description char(200))
RETURNS char(200)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 
   Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(
   Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(
   Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(
   Replace(RTRIM(:description)
       ,'%','%25')       ,'&','%26')       ,'$','%24')       ,'+','%2B')
       ,',','%2C')       ,':','%3A')       ,';','%3B')       ,'=','%3C')
       ,'?','%3D')       ,':','%3F')       ,'@','%40')       ,'#','%23')
       ,'<','%3C')       ,'>','%3E')       ,'[','%5B')       ,']','%5D')
       ,'{','%7B')       ,'}','%7D')       ,'|','%7C')       ,'^','%5E')
       ,' ','%20')       ,'~','%7E')       ,'`','%60')       ,'*','%2A')
       ,'(','%28')       ,')','%29')       ,'/','%2F')       ,'\\','%5C')
       ,' ','%20') INTO :description;
  RETURN :description;
END;
```

Comment: Is this syntax above applicable to [Pervasive 13](https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/#page/sqlref%2Fsqlref.CREATE_FUNCTION.htm)?

Comment: I did write it using version 14, it should also run under version 13 (and any other version).

Comment: oops, there is a missing '\'

Comment: It's a shame they don't provide a built-in function for this, as it would allow me to perform the query without making any modifications to the database. Thanks for creating this custom function, though.